# Avoid traceback after CTRL+C in async

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, pyrogram

I'm currently exploring async/await in python.

I'd like to start Pyrogram, then run the cronjob function. I created this code:

```
import asyncio
from pyrogram import Client, Filters, MessageHandler
import time

app = Client("pihome")

async def cronjob():
    print("Cronjob started")
    while True:
        #print(f"time is {time.strftime('%X')}")
        print(int(time.time()))
        if int(time.strftime('%S')) == 10:
            print("SECONDO 10") # Change this with checks in future

        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    print(f"Starting {app.session_name}...\n")
    # Pyrogram
    await app.start()
    print("Pyrogram started")

    # Cronjob
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.create_task(await cronjob()))
    print("\nDone")

    await Client.idle()
    await app.stop()

    print(f"\nStopping {app.session_name}...")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

But when i want to stop it with Ctrl+C it gives me this traceback:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "pihome.py", line 39, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 570, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1823, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/selectors.py", line 468, in select
    fd_event_list = self._selector.poll(timeout, max_ev)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

How can I solve it? Also, try/except blocks seem not working

Answer (score 1):

1. To run the application, it is better to use [asyncio.run(main())](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-an-asyncio-program). In my opinion, it’s more clear.
2. Replace loop = asyncio.[new_event_loop()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html) by loop = asyncio.[get_event_loop()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html). Because using asyncio.new_event_loop() after asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main()) you create a second event loop in main thread which is prohibited. Only one event loop per thread is permitted!
3. Remove **await** from this line:

   loop.run_until_complete(loop.create_task(await cronjob()))

Because [create_task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html) need to [Coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutine) as the first argument but you pass it None

Comment: Update my answer

Comment: i can't run asyncio.run because the owner of pyrogram told me it's bugged. sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to catch `KeyboardInnterrupt` exception generated in `run_until_complete` and it prevents from showing traceback in the console:

```
async def main():
    print(f"Starting {app.session_name}...\n")
    # Pyrogram
    await app.start()
    print("Pyrogram started")

    # Cronjob
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(loop.create_task(await cronjob()))
    
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("CTRL-C was pressed")

    finnaly:
        print("\nDone")

    await Client.idle()
    await app.stop()

    print(f"\nStopping {app.session_name}...")
```